# Multi-user realtime drawing in iPhone

Tags: iphone, drawing, real-time, interactive

Im going to create an applicaition for i-phone as a multi-user ineractive drawing. what i mean is some thing like YM functionality that 2 or mutiple user can draw at the same time together and. do you have any idea or clue for me to how to start? 
I have some methods in my mind , like making an webview and my drawing pad be coded using javascript libraies. or i use drawing methods in iphone then every second for example i save the state of the screen in a database and meanwhile i pull the data from data base again repeatedly,,, how ever these methods dosen look logical..

I would really appreciate it if you can help me .. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely avoid webviews and write a native iPhone app. To start I would look for GameKit examples -- it has the concept of finding other players built in and your app is functionally equivalent to a game (collect touches, change a shared state, get it to all participants).

If you want to go the WebView way, just make it a website that is Safari Mobile compatible and bypass the iPhone programming completely.